# Php Pagination backwards

Tags: php, pagination

I have this part of the code for my pagination that display records backwards. And it works well but is only tested on 24 pages. It has to be adjusted to support much more (100+).

And the pager to look like

```
24 23 22 21 20 (current 19) 18 17 16 15 14 ... 2 1

24 23 ... 14 13 12 11 10 (current 9) 8 7 6 5 4 ... 2 1

24 23 ...  11 10 9 8 7 (current 6) 5 4 3 2 1
```

My code:

```
 <?php
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM table ");
$total_results = $result->num_rows;
$result->close();

    /* Setup vars for query. */

    $targetpage = "moving-articles";
    $limit = 15; 
    $adjacents = 5;
    $lastpage = ceil($total_results/$limit);                                
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if( $page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;  
    else
        $start = ($lastpage - 1) * $limit;; 

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = $mysqli->query("(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY datestamp LIMIT $start, $limit) ORDER BY datestamp DESC");
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                          

    if ($page == '') $page = $lastpage; //if no page var is given, default to last page (as first page)
    /* Draw the pagination object.  */

 $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "
        <div class='pagination'>";
        /* Next Button */
        if ($page < $lastpage) 
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$next/'>« next</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>« next</span>";   

        if ($lastpage < $adjacents * 4) //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
        /* Backwards Pagination */
        for ($counter = $lastpage; $counter > 0; $counter--) {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";
        }
        }

        else if($lastpage > $adjacents * 4) //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page > $lastpage - $adjacents * 2)      
            {

                for ($counter = $lastpage ; $counter > $adjacents * 2; $counter--)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";                  
                }

                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/2/'>2</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/1/'>1</a>";

            }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
            else if($page < $lastpage - $adjacents * 2 && $page > $adjacents * 2)
            {

                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lastpage/'>$lastpage</a>";    
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lpm1/'>$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lpm1 - $adjacents; $counter - $adjacents *2 > 2; $counter--)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";                  
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/2/'>2</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/1/'>1</a>";

            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lastpage/'>$lastpage</a>";    
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lpm1/'>$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lpm1 - $adjacents * 2; $counter >= 1; $counter--)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";                  
                }
            }

        }


        /* Previous Button */
        if ($page > $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$prev/'>previous »</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>previous »</span>";

        $pagination.= "</div>";     
    }

?>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you please post the whole code? its only elseif as I understood.And also, is this your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination in reverse order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816425/pagination-in-reverse-order)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate because it is not just the reversed order but the algorithm itself

Comment: @user1551066 I updeted the code. This is what i have so far. And it is not a duplicate, idea is the same but i want to have it more advanced and also ready to support big numbers of pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM table");
$total_results = $result->num_rows;
$result->close();

    /* Setup vars for query. */

    $targetpage = "moving-articles";
    $limit = 5; 
    $adjacents = 5;
    $lastpage = ceil($total_results/$limit);                                
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if( $page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;  
    else
        $start = ($lastpage - 1) * $limit;; 

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = $mysqli->query("(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY datestamp LIMIT $start, $limit) ORDER BY datestamp DESC");
    if ($page == '') $page = $lastpage; //if no page var is given, default to last page (as first page)
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                          


    /* Draw the pagination object.  */

    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "
        <div class='pagination'>";
        /* Next Button */
        if ($page < $lastpage) 
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$next/'>« next</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>« next</span>";   

        if ($lastpage < $adjacents * 4) //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
        /* Backwards Pagination */
        for ($counter = $lastpage; $counter > 0; $counter--) {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";
        }
        }

        else if($lastpage > $adjacents * 4) //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page > $lastpage - $adjacents * 2)      
            {

                for ($counter = $lastpage ; $counter > abs(($adjacents * 2) - $lastpage) - 1; $counter--)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";                  
                }

                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/2/'>2</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/1/'>1</a>";

            }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
            else if($page <= $lastpage - $adjacents * 2 && $page > $adjacents * 2)
            {

                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lastpage/'>$lastpage</a>";    
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lpm1/'>$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page + $adjacents; $counter > $page - $adjacents - 1 ; $counter--)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";                  
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/2/'>2</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/1/'>1</a>";

            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lastpage/'>$lastpage</a>";    
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$lpm1/'>$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = ($adjacents * 2) +1 ; $counter >= 1; $counter--)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$counter/'>$counter</a>";                  
                }
            }

        }


        /* Previous Button */
        if ($page > $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage/page/$prev/'>previous »</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>previous »</span>";

        $pagination.= "</div>";     
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but try to use this loop

```
for ($counter = $lpm1 - $adjacents; $counter - $adjacents > 2; $counter--)
```

If it returns wrong number but reversed order is correct then post the result in this answer I will try to think how to fix it

Comment: I updated code again. 
« next 24 23...18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 ... 2 1 previous »
so in the range starting from 18 page to 8 navigation works good. But i would like ellipsis to move with current page by 5 pages to to the left + and 5 pages to the right -.

Comment: Say, in this order 24 23 ... 16 15 14 13 12 (current 11) 10 9 8 7 6 ... 2 1 you click on 9. How the pager supposed to look (I mean ellipsises)?

Comment: I manage to make it work mor less how i want.  I updated the question and the code! So with the code I have at the moment it fine as long as i have +- 24 pages, and pager to look  24 23 ... 14 13 12 11 10 (current 9) 8 7 6 5 4 ... 2 1,